# How do I properly import Python classes?

Tags: python, class, python-import

First, my folder structure is as follows:
[image]

My `BaseScraper.py` has:

```
class BaseScraper:
    def __init__(self, page=0, min_code_size=300):
        self.page = page
        self.MIN_CODE_SIZE = min_code_size
    ...
```

My `JSScraper.py` has:

```
from BaseScraper import BaseScraper


class JSScraper(BaseScraper):
    def __init__(self):
        super(self).__init__(*args)
```

And my `jsscraper.py` (that runs it all) has:

```
from Scraper import JSScraper

scraper = JSScraper.JSScraper(page=0)
```

So when I run `jsscraper.py`, I get:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'BaseScraper'
```

I don't fully get how I'm supposed to structure these projects to properly import and deal with classes. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: See https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html

Comment: When you run `python jsscraper.py` in your top directory of the project, that directory will be put in `sys.path`. That means the current directory will be searched when looking for python packages. It is important to note that when you call `jsscript.py` from somewhere else, like `python a/b/c/jsscript.py`, the path added to `sys.path` is still the directory with `jsscript.py` not the directory you call `python` from. This could be confusing. To debug your issue, print the contents of `sys.path` and check if `Scraper` directory is in one of the directories listed there.

Comment: Take a look here: http://www.owsiak.org/i-hate-python-importing-modules-from-subdirectories/ and here for a super simple sample: https://github.com/mkowsiak/pythonmodules

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### How to import

First of you should almost always use `import X` over `from X import *`. This is due to how X is imported.

In short, if you use `import X` there is a reference created to X that you can access, via this reference you can access all properties of X like `X.property`.

If you use `from X import *` however you import references to all the properties of X. This means you can access a property from X by simply typing `property`. The downside of this is that if you already have a property with the same name it will be overwritten.

For more information on imports you can read [this article](http://effbot.org/zone/import-confusion.htm)

### Solution to the problem

Coming back to your problem; To fix the import problems you should import like this;

**jsscraper.py**:

```
import Scraper.JSScraper
# Access the scraper via JSScraper.JSScraper()
```

**Scraper.JSScraper.py**:
(Note that you forgot to prepend Scraper in your import that caused the error)

```
import Scraper.BaseScraper
# Access the base scraper via BaseScraper.BaseScraper()
```

### More readable solution

For a more readable solution you can also use an alias for an import
 like `import X.Y as z` which you can access like `z.property`

For you this means the following:

```
import Scraper.JSScraper as scraper
# Access the scraper via scraper.JSScraper()
```

**Scraper.JSScraper.py**:
(Note that you forgot to prepend Scraper in your import that caused the error)

```
import Scraper.BaseScraper as base
# Access the base scraper via base.BaseScraper()
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `jsscraper.py` file you wrote `from BaseScraper import BaseScraper`. 
(I'm not an expert in Python) I guess it will works if you write it like that
for "JSScraper.py":

```
from Scraper.BaseScraper import BaseScraper
```

Because Python thinks that "BaseScraper" after the "from" (`from BaseScraper ...)`is a directory and not the Filename where your class is.

Well, as a result you have to change your "jsscraper.py" too into:

```
from Scraper.JSScraper import JSScraper
```

Like I already said I guess my explanation is a little bit (or really) wrong. But I hope that I could help you. (Sorry for bad english)